# How can I position my rating bar in this situation css html?

Tags: html, css

see the code below and run it, I want to place the rating bar next to Effective:, how can I do that. I have tried to use float:left, it fail because it shift the whole fieldset to the left which is in front of the textarea. How can I place the rating bar next to the Effective, appreciate.

```css
.rating:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    clip:rect(0,0,0,0);
}

#rating_1:not(:checked) > label {
    float:right;
    width:9px;
 padding:0 .1em 0 0;
 border-left:.1em solid #fff;/* make space between content*/
 overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:200%;
    line-height:0.9;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #bbb, 2px 2px #666, .1em .1em .2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

#rating_1:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content:'\00a0 \00a0 \00a0 ';
    background-color: #c7c5c5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    border-radius: 1px; 
}

#rating_1 > input:checked ~ label:before {
 content:'\00a0 \00a0 \00a0 ';
 background-color: #4bce32;
}

#rating_1:not(:checked) :hover ~ label:before {
content:'\00a0 \00a0 \00a0 ';
background-color: #4bce32;

}
```

```html
<div class="user_voting" id="faith_voting">
  <span>My faith:</span>   
  <textarea   maxlength="99" class="expand1-99" id="faith_t"  name="faith_t" placeholder="..."  onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='...'" ></textarea>
      <filedset class="rating" id="rating_1">Effective:
      <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5" title="Rocks!">5 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4" title="Pretty good">4 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="Meh">3 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2" title="Kinda bad">2 stars</label>
      <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1" title="Sucks big time">1 star</label>
  </fieldset>
  </div>
```

Comment: You want the texts to the left and the box to the right?

Comment: There are many different ways to do a layout.  Here is a very quick example. http://jsfiddle.net/k2Lq7mjh/

Comment: Troy Thompson, Thank you very much!